# How to extend display of my laptop to TV

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, extended-desktop

I have a HP Pavilion g6-2265sx Notebook PC running Windows 10 Enterprise x64 having 1 HDMI 1.4 out port and Intel HD Graphics 4000 with the latest drivers.

I have a Samsung HDTV Model : UA46ES7500R with 3 HDMI in ports.

1. HDMI/DVI
2. HDMI/ARC
3. HDMI/MHL

I purchased a 10 meters long HDMI 1.4 cable, first connected one end to HDMI/DVI port on the TV then connected the other end to the sole HDMI port on my computer.

Booted up the computer and pressed Win+P to extend my display on the TV. When I select extend the laptops screen flickers for a brief moment and comes back on. I select the HDMI 1 source on the TV nothing shows up except the message "This source is not connected. Please check the connection again".

Firing up the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel shows that my Samsung TV is detected.

The initial refresh rate was 59p so I changed it to 60p to match my laptop but it did not help.

[Samsung Display setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF4P3.png)

This is the display setting for my laptop.

[laptop display setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKjpZ.png)

I still cannot extend my laptop display to my TV using HDMI.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yay!!! Tumbleweed badge

Answer (score 0):

Guys It was a faulty cable. Used a relatively expensive HDMI cable and it worked like a charm